# Load multiples .txt files in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 1,000 .txt files that I want to put in the same SQL table. All those files have exactly the same information: the DMP I use creates a new .txt files every hour... Each new file that is created have a "header" and the idea is that I only want to have 1 header at the end. So this is what I find in my directory folder after 1000 hours for instance:

```
nameoffile1.txt
nameoffile2.txt
nameoffile3.txt
...
nameoffile1000.txt
```

How can I insert this files in my table without having to write 1,000 times:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Users/xxxx/Desktop/Folder/nameoffile1.txt'
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Users/xxxx/Desktop/Folder/nameoffile2.txt'
```

... and keeping only 1 header at the end?

Thank you very much for your help :)

NB1: I have already investigated previous topics, but I couldn't find an answer for Mysql.
NB2 : I know how to do it with the Terminal but I want to know how to do it via Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If all your text file has a same format. First create a suitable table on you Database, then create a upload.bat file, put it and all your text files in C:/import (or any folder name without space in C: drive). All your text files's names should not have space too.

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
  set old=%%~dpnxf
  set new=!old:\=\\!
  "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -e "load data local infile '"!new!"' IGNORE into table YOUR_TABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS " -h 127.0.0.1 -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD YOUR_SCHEMA
  echo UPLOAD %%~nxf DONE
)

pause
```

Then try running this the bat file